# Reduce the width of search box in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, search

please vist "http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/"

I wanted to remove REGISTER and SIGN IN, which is present above the search box. Also I wnat to reduce the WIDTH of  the SEARCH BOX.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some simple CSS. You should remove the register and sign in links from the template but this will have the desired effect:

```
/* Remove the register & sign in buttons */
.header-bottom-content ul.link-bottom {
    display: none;
}

/* Reduce the size of the search box */
.form-search input.input-text {
    width: 250px; /* Change to desired width */
}
```

Simply add it at the bottom of your themes CSS file. You'll want to update **width: 250px;** to the desired width of the search box. You will end up with a large white gap between the search box and the basket button which isn't ideal.

Comment: @user3483987 just add it at the very bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To change WIDTH of the SEARCH BOX, you can do following steps:

1. Open styles-l.css in folder: `InstallationRootFolder\pub\static\frontend\YourNameSpace\YourThemeName\en_US\css`
2. Edit following lines:
   `.block-search{position: relative;float: right;padding-left: 15px;width: 550px;z-index: 4}` 
   [Change width as per your requirements]
3. Upload and refresh Cache

You can check immediate change in width in front-end... :)